# Java: How do a make a variable outside of the loop that remembers the int made in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, shapes

The prompt requests that I adapt code I wrote to generate a Sierpinski triangle to make a Sierpinski "square" (conceptually similar to a Sierpinski carpet, but simplified).

My code is as follows:

```
public static void drawQuadChaos(double ax, double ay, 
                                     double bx, double by,
                                     double cx, double cy,
                                     double dx, double dy,
                                     int nPoints) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    
    StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.03);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
    StdDraw.point(ax, ay);
    StdDraw.point(bx, by);
    StdDraw.point(cx, cy);
    StdDraw.point(dx, dy);
    
    StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.005);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
    
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
        double choice = rand.nextInt(4);
        if (choice == 0){
            x = (x + ax) / 2.0;
            y = (y + ay) / 2.0;
        }
        else if (choice == 1){
            x = (x + bx) / 2.0;
            y = (y + by) / 2.0;
        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            x = (x + cx) / 2.0;
            y = (y + cy) / 2.0;
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            x = (x + dx) / 2.0;
            y = (y + dy) / 2.0;
        }
        StdDraw.point(x, y);
    }
    
}

/*public static boolean storeDecisions(double x, double y) {
    while ( x != 0.0 && y != 0.0) {
        if (x % 3 == 1 && y % 3 == 1)
            return false;
        x /= 3;
        y /= 3;
    }
    return true;
}*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawQuadChaos(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, 20000);
}
```

I was able to make a square, but unlike the triangle the points inside have no pattern [like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSuJC.png)

I believe the issue is that points are being repeated, and I have to make a variable outside of the loop that remembers the last choice made and avoids it for each subsequent loop iteration.

I think I need to make a variable before the main loop whose job is to remember the int, then can set that variable to whatever choice that was made at the end of each loop iteration. Then, at the next iteration it can check the variable when a new random choice is made.

However, I am unsure of how to write that variable. While I can use an array or recursive method, I have been told that a simple while loop or for loop would work, but I do not know how to arrange that for this specific case. I have had this issue for several days, and this is my last resort. Any advice on how to resolve this issue? Insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I figured it out! I modified the for loop as follows:

```
    double lastX = ax;
    double lastY = ay;
    
    double lastChoice = 0.0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
        double choice = rand.nextInt(4);
        while (choice == lastChoice) {
            choice = rand.nextInt(4);
        }
        if (choice == 0){
            lastX = (lastX + ax) / 2.0;
            lastY = (lastY + ay) / 2.0;
        }
        else if (choice == 1){
            lastX = (lastX + bx) / 2.0;
            lastY = (lastY + by) / 2.0;
        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            lastX = (lastX + cx) / 2.0;
            lastY = (lastY + cy) / 2.0;
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            lastX = (lastX + dx) / 2.0;
            lastY = (lastY + dy) / 2.0;
        }
        StdDraw.point(lastX, lastY);
        lastChoice = choice;
    }
```

This modification redefines "choice" every the time the code runs through this loop and stores it in "lastChoice", so it will not repeat the previously made mistake.

Comment: `int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
x = i;
}  
System.out.println(x);`  Not saying that solves your problem.  Just that that's how to declare variables outside of a loop.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but that already seems structurally similar to the for loop I already have. Is there a distinction between the two? (EDIT: I think the big lingering issue is that I do not know how to take the point generated in established loop (x, y) and work that into another, separate for loop.)

Comment: Or just define choice outside the loop and you don't need to copy the variable.

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative to this is also to instantiate the variable outside the loop:

```
int i = 0;
```

and then use a while loop for the same purpose, and increment the variable each time within the loops. That way you will still have the variable once its out of scope

```
int i = 0;
while (i<npoints){
  //... rest of your code
  i++;
}
```